# How could I add a column to a DataFrame in Pyspark with incremental values?

Tags: python, dataframe, attributes, pyspark, increment

I have a DataFrame called 'df' like the following:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|  Atr1 |  Atr2 |  Atr3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   A   |   A   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   B   |   A   |   A   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   C   |   A   |   A   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to add a new column to it with incremental values and get the following updated DataFrame:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Atr1 |  Atr2 |  Atr3 |  Atr4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   A   |   A   |   1   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   B   |   A   |   A   |   2   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   C   |   A   |   A   |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

How could I get it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only need incremental values (like an ID) and **if there is no constraint that the numbers need to be consecutive**, you could use `monotonically_increasing_id()`. The only guarantee when using this function is that the values will be increasing for each row, however, the values themself can differ each execution.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df.withColumn("Atr4", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution!

Comment: Note that this answer does in fact address the question, however it should be noted given the example specifies a dataframe "like the following", one might assume the example would extend to an infinite amount of consecutive numbers, however `monotonically_increasing_id()` does not produce consecutive numbers, only monotonically increasing numbers and thus the assumption would break down with a larger dataframe.

Comment: @Jomonsugi: That is correct. I highlighted that part of the answer to make this constraint more obvious.