# How to generate id and put in pyspark df?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading data from a hive table and creating DataFrame in pyspark using:

```
hive_df = sqlContext.sql("select * from table")
```

The DataFrame `hive_df` has three columns: `(cust_id, name, l_name)`

In `hive table` the `cust_id` field is `null` for all the records, so I want to put some value, in incremental manner.

**Data in hive table**

```
cust_id,name,l_name
       , abc,   def
       , ghi,   jkl
       , mno,   pqr
```

**Desired Output**

```
cust_id,name,l_name
   1000, abc,   def
   1001, ghi,   jkl
   1002, mno,   pqr
```

Comment: use [`pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) like this: `from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id; hive_df = hive_df.withColumn("cust_id", monotonically_increasing_id())`

Comment: If the starting value does not matter see this question, ie. the monotonically increasing id:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213986/how-could-i-add-a-column-to-a-dataframe-in-pyspark-with-incremental-values

Comment: its working for me thank you pault and dorvak, its possible that counter will start from some initial value, I want to give 1000.